# An example of locally compact connected group which is not perfect

Tags: connectedness, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

I would like to find an example of locally compact connected group $G$ which the commutator subgroup $G$ is not $G$ itself.

Comment: Any locally compact connected abelian group will work, e.g. $\mathbb R$

Answer (score 1):

What about $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb R)_+$ (that is $\{g\in\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb R)\mid\det g>0\}$)? Its commutator subgroup is $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb R)$.